# Speaker and Mic stoped working on MotoG (1st Gen) after upgrade

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, audio, motorola-moto-g, microphone, speaker

**Problem:**

One day my mobile was dead because of empty battery. I recharged the battery and turned on the mobile. Mobile showed a message "Android is upgrading" while turning on. After that Speaker and Mic are not working. There is no any type of sound coming out of mobile and I cant input my voice through mic. Sometimes Phone app acts very slow.

**Configurations:**

- MotoG 1st Generation
- Android 5.0.2 (Lollipop)
- Build No. LXB22.46-28
- Dual Sim
- Internal Memory 16 GB

**What I have tried:**

- Restarted my mobile many times *(No Result)*
- Restarted my mobile with Safe Mode *(No Result)*
- Factory Reset *(No Result)*
- Clear Cache Partition *(No Result)*
- Once I restarted with QCom option from power options ***(Speaker and Mic started working . I restarted again with normal mode and still speaker and mic was working but after some minutes speaker and mic were dead again)***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly I was able to fix this issue in my phone by changing following wi-fi settings:

Go to advanced wi-fi setting. You will find a toggle option "Scanning always available". Disable this option.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem in my moto g 1st generation with **Mic only**.

I have also tried some option as you said. See my efforts at

[Moto G  Microphone is not working](http://shareprogrammingtips.com/moto-g-microphone-volume-issue-fixed/)

After update also it was not working. But after cleaning MIC hole in my mobile now its working fine.